# C++ Float Comparison Around Zero Fails With Gtest

Tags: c++, floating-point, googletest, numerical

we are struggling with one unit test of mine for quite some while. During investigation we have found the root cause, which seems to be the comparison in floats (see the following code snippet where I have simplified the computation but it still fails).

```
TEST_F( MyFloatTest, thisOneDoesFail)
{
    const float toCompare = 0.2f - 1.0f + 0.9f;
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ( toCompare, 0.1f );
}
```

The result is:

> Actual: 0.1
>     Expected: toCompare
>     Which is: 0.099999964

Having some background in numerical mathematics, we still can't figure out why this test fails, while a custom float comparison using std::numerical_limits::epsilon passed. 
So at some point we began to think, that GTest is wrong and we debugged into it. It uses strange expressions, that we do not fully grab.
What is even stranger: The following test passes, even though I just add a 1:

```
TEST_F( MyFloatTest, thisOnePasses)
{
    const float toCompare = 1.2f - 1.0f + 0.9f;
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ( toCompare, 1.1f );
}
```

We thought it might be some problem when including negative float values, but the next test also passes:

```
TEST_F( MyFloatTest, thisOnePassesAlso)
{
    const float toCompare = 0.2f - 1.0f + 1.9f;
    EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ( toCompare, 1.1f );
}
```

So for us it seems as the EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ macro of Gtest does simply have a problem around zero.
Does anyone know of this behaviour? Have you ever saw similar in your environment? (btw: we use the MSVC2015) Does it just fail by accident due to the 4 ULP precision mentioned in GTest? (which is also not completely clear to us).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1) might help

Comment: What about showing is the EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a floating-point sum with a small value and large intermediate values will tend to have a large relative error. You reduce the error by writing

```
const float toCompare = 0.2f - (1.0f - 0.9f);
```

In your original code, the largest intermediate value was 0.2 - 1.0 = -0.8, eight times larger than the final result. With the changed code, the largest intermediate value is 0.1, equal to the final result. And if you check your example tests that passed, in each case you have no intermediate results that are large compared to the final result.

The problem is not with the EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ macro, but with the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, adding the parenthesizes actually solved the problem and EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ does not fail anymore! In my case 0.9f is not fixed though (it is just added here for reasons of simplification), so I will take a second look in my computation, but now I know where to take a look.

Answer (score 5):

> Does it just fail by accident due to the 4 ULP precision mentioned in GTest?

That seems to me the case.

Try the following (very crude, not portable!) test code:

```
float toCompare = 0.2f - 1.0f + 0.9f;
int i = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&toCompare);
std::cout << i << '\n';
float expected = 0.1f;
i = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&expected);
std::cout << i << '\n';
```

On my system the output is:

```
1036831944
1036831949
```

The mantissae are exactly 5 ULPs apart. The 4 ULP comparison is not sufficient for the error of the calculation.

`0.2f - 1.0f` is fine, there is no accuracy error at all on my system. What you're left with is `-0.8f + 0.9f`. This is where the error comes from (on my system). I'm not an expert enough to tell you *why* this calculation has 5 ULP accuracy error.

---

In cases where certain degree of error is expected, use [`EXPECT_NEAR`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#floating-point-macros).

Answer (score 0):

As I see it the problem is your assumption that 0.2f - 1.0f + 0.9f is equal to 0.1f. None of 0.2 0.9 0.1 can be represented exactly as floats (or as doubles or any other binary floating point representation).

0.2f and 0.9f will in fact be approximations to 0.2 and 0.9, and there is little reason to suppose that the your sum will give the same approximation to 0.1 as given by 0.1f. While the relative error in 0.2f and 0.9f will all be roughly the same, the relative error in the sum could be much larger because of the cancellation.

If you try the same thing with numbers that can be exactly represented as floats, for example 0.25f - 1.0f + 0.875f you will find that this is equal to 0.125f